# How Can I Use an Element of a Tuple as an Argument for a Pure Function?

Tags: list-manipulation, pure-function

(If I should elaborate on the circumstances, tell me.)

I want to do the following: Suppose I have a tuple

```
 tuple={x,4,something,...}
```

and I want to define a pure function, e.g.

```
Function[{tuple[[1]]},x^2]
```

What I expect is that it uses the first element of tuple as the variable in x^2, that is x.
However, what I get is that {tuple[[1]]} is not a list of symbols.

(Evaluate around tuple does not help.)

Can someone explain why this does not work and how it would work?

EDIT: So apparently my remark "Evaluate around tuple does not help." was not quite correct. To fix this, one simply has to do `Evaluate@{tuple[[1]]}` rather than (what I tried first) `{Evaluate@tuple[[1]]}`

Comment: Context: I defined a custom Integration that should work with the same syntax as the normal Integrate: cIntegrate[f,{x,x2,x2}], where I need to parse x, the first element of my tuple, as the variable to be integrated. The reason is something about speed of this operation

Comment: Use this form instead.  `(#^2)&[tuple[[1]]]` The way you did it does not work since `tuple[[1]]` is not a formal parameter name

Comment: @Nasser But this is backwards from what I'm doing. If I already have my pure Function in the form (#^2)&, I would be done already. The Problem is, that I have an algebraic expression such as "x^2" and I want to convert it to (#^2)& using the built-in Function[]. And the Argument I want it to convert is given by an element of a tuple, i.e. "x" here.

Comment: Then what command is there (if at all), to tell Mathematica that tuple[[1]] (that is, the first element of tuple) is my parameter name?

Comment: Function has the attribute  "HoldAll". Therefore you need "Evalaue":  Function[Evaluate[{tuple[[1]]}], x^2]

Comment: @DanielHuber It is funny, I tried the same thing, but with Evaluate around tuple, rather than {tuple} and it did not work. So this is why I asked in the first place. (See my remark in the question, that "evaluate around tuple does not work"). So uhm... thanks. I guess I was close. Should I delete this question? Obviously I knew the answer but made a slight mistake

Comment: I would write an addendum with the correct answer for other people who may have the same problem.

Comment: @Confuse-ray30 You should just answer your own question with an official answer rather than editing your OP with the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently my remark "Evaluate around tuple does not help." was not quite correct. To fix this, one simply has to do `Evaluate@{tuple[[1]]}` rather than (what I tried first) `{Evaluate@tuple[[1]]}`